# What is the difference between Einstein aether theory and general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, aether

I'm currently doing some research on the various aether theories and I stumbled upon [Einstein aether theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_aether_theory). It appears to be much different from [Luminiferous aether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether) and be more closely related to [general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity).

What are the key differences between Einsten's aether theory and general relativity?

Comment: It's not _Einstein's aether theory_, it's _Einstein_ aether theory. Namely, it's a modification of general relativity that introduces a new object that, some might argue, depending on how you look at it, kind of has, one could say, a tiny little bit in common, perhaps, with the pre-relativity ether. Einstein himself had nothing to do with it.

Comment: Einstein aether theory is one of perhaps a hundred different theories that modify general relativity by adding extra bells and whistles. At present there is no direct evidence for any of them, though.

Comment: What do you want to know that isn't discussed in the Wikipedia article that you linked to?

Comment: @BenCrowell Mostly the key differences between them, presented in a way that is somewhat manageable to understand without specialised knowledge of the field.